# Can I log the flight as the authorized instructor on board? Commercial long cross country

Tags: faa-regulations, commercial-aviation, logging

I was an authorized instructor on board for my students long commercial cross country. Do I log any of that flight time?

Comment: were you actively providing instruction? If not, you were a passenger. Whether it'd be legal or not to log that time, unless you were doing the job I'd consider it unethical.

Comment: I would expect that if you wee required to be there, you can log it.  It's a long time since I got my commercial, but, the way I remember it, the pilot learning to be a commercial pilot had to do the long cross-country on his or her own.    So I'm having trouble understanding your question.  Unless I did one with an instructor and then one on my own and I'm not remembering correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Answer solved,

https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2014/Kuhn_2014_Legal_Interpretation.pdf

Short terms, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an FAA Certificated Flight Instructor serving as the "authorized instructor," and you are rated to act as pilot in command of that aircraft, according to [14 CFR 61.51(e)(3)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.51(e)(3)) you may log the flight time as pilot in command.

[14 CFR 61.51 (e)(3)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.51(e)(3)) states:

> (3) A certificated flight instructor may log pilot in command flight time for all flight time while serving as the authorized instructor in an operation if the instructor is rated to act as pilot in command of that aircraft.